# dependency cycle detected import/no-cycle

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I am trying to set up API endpoints in ES6. In my main server file, I tried to import the router module but I get the error "dependency cycle detected import/no-cycle". Please find my code below for clearance and assistance.

```
import express from 'express';

import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

import router from './routes/routes';

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// app.use(routes);

app.use('/api/v1', router);

const run = () => console.log('way to go server!');

app.listen(PORT, run);
export default app;
```

Comment: The question doesn't contain the code that could be responsible for circular dependency, ./routes/routes and whatever else. The question should contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: A possible solution to a variation of this problem: if you're using TypeScript and your dependency cycle is just because your type definitions have a circular reference, try prefixing your imported type with `type`, so for example you add the `type` prefix here: `import { type YourType } from "@/foo/bar";`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This could be a direct reference `(A -> B -> A)` issue, which even you might be doing.

```
// file a.ts
import { b } from 'b';
...
export a;

// file b.ts
import { a } from 'a';
...
export b;
```

Read [HERE](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/06/25/circular-dependencies-javascript/) more about "Eliminate Circular Dependencies from Your JavaScript Project":

Once I had the issue in **vue.js** project and the code that had issue was something like this:

```
<script>
  import router from '@/router';
  import { requestSignOut } from '../../api/api';

  export default {
    name: 'sign-out',
    mounted() {
      requestSignOut().then((data) => {
        if (data.status === 'ok') {
          router.push({ name: 'sign-in' });
        }
      });
    },
  };
</script>
```

Then I fixed it this way:

```
<script>
import { requestSignOut } from '@/api/api';

export default {
  name: 'sign-out',
  mounted() {
    requestSignOut().then((data) => {
      if (data.status === 'ok') {
        this.$router.push({ name: 'sign-in' });
      }
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate with example ? I don't understand the possible issues. I have a react project and just activated eslint. I got about 10 "import/no-cycle" but my app seems to have no problem. I am thinking about desactivating the rule. I can't find why cycles are bad

Comment: Cycles bad, searching for relevant articles good.
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12005/why-are-cyclic-imports-considered-so-evil